How do we know $x$ is fixed in $\sum_{y \in Y}f(x,y)$?
The following result comes from Analysis I by Terence Tao.

Let $X, Y$ be finite sets, and let $f : X \times Y \to \mathbf{R}$ be a function. Then
$$
\sum_{x \in X}\left(\sum_{y \in Y}f(x,y)\right) = \sum_{(x,y) \in X \times Y} f(x,y)
$$


Tao uses a proof by induction, by letting $X$ have $n$ elements and inducting on $n$.
When considering the base case $n = 0$, it's easy to see that
$$
\sum_{(x,y) \in X \times Y} f(x,y) = 0
$$
by using the following result:

If $X$ is empty, and $f: X \to \mathbb{R}$ is a function, we have
$$
\sum_{x \in X} f(x) = 0
$$

But now we have to show that $\sum_{x \in X}\left(\sum_{y \in Y}f(x,y)\right) =0$.
At first, I questioned how the term $\sum_{y \in Y}f(x,y)$ is even defined based on the definitions presented in the text. The only way it can be is if we observe that $x$ is a fixed value. But why can we assume $x$ is indeed fixed?. What mathematical/logical argument can be made to assert it?
Once we bybass that, we can then define a bijection $h: \{i \in \mathbb{N} : 1 \leq i \leq 0\} \to \{x\} \times Y$, implying
$$
\sum_{x \in X}\left(\sum_{y \in Y}f(x,y)\right) = 
\sum_{x \in X}\left(\sum_{i=1}^{0}f(h(i))\right) =\sum_{x \in X}\ 0 = 0
$$

EDIT.
My main question above still stands, but I think what followed was too involved. Instead, we can define $k : X \to \mathbb{R}$ (and hence $k$ is the empty function) by $k(x) = \sum_{y \in Y}f(x,y)$. Then we have
$$
\sum_{x \in X}\left(\sum_{y \in Y}f(x,y)\right) = \sum_{x \in X} k(x) = 0
$$

You may be overcomplicating it.  The outer sum is determining the value of $x$ while you're inside the context of its summand. Think of it as a "for loop" in your favorite programming language.

@NickPeterson, okay I do see that, but I still need to somehow relate the sum on the left-hand side of the equation in the result to a sum of a sequence.

For each fixed $x' \in X$, the sum $\sum_{y \in Y}f(x',y)$ is defined, and has a
real value.  This, in other words, is a map that maps each $x' \in X$ to a real number $\sum_{y \in Y}f(x',y)$. We write this as $$x' \to \sum_{y \in Y}f(x',y)$$ or if we call it function (map) $g : X \to \mathbb R$, we write $$g(x') = \sum_{y \in Y}f(x',y).$$
As $x'$ is a dummy variable that represents an arbitrary element of the set $X$, there is essentially no difference in using $x'$ or $x$ to denote this dummy variable. Hence, $$g \ : \ x \to \sum_{y \in Y}f(x,y)$$ or $$g(x) = \sum_{y \in Y}f(x,y).$$
Coming to your question, when we look at the sum $$\sum_{x \in X}\left(\sum_{y \in Y}f(x,y)\right),$$ as Nick Peterson pointed out too, the outer sum fixes an $x\in X$, and computes the corresponding sum $\sum_{y \in Y}f(x,y)$ for that fixed $x \in X$.
For the sake of a simple example, in a similar manner, we can perceive the sum $\sum\limits_{i \in \{1,2,3\}} i^2$ as follows. At each step (without replacement), we fix $i$ to be equal to an element of the set $\{1,2,3\}$, then calculate $i^2$ that corresponds to that fixed value of $i$. And what the sum $\Sigma$ does is to add up these $i^2$.
In your question, similar to fixing $i$ and computing the corresponding $i^2$ at each step, what you do is that you fix an $x \in X$ and compute the corresponding $\sum_{y \in Y}f(x,y)$ at each step.
In summary, the term $\sum_{y \in Y}f(x,y)$ is defined for each fixed $x \in X$, and therefore everything you have written in your post is well-defined and makes sense.
